# Null pointer exception for string array

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, arrays

I have the following code and i get Null pointer exception at this line: `unWanted[g].equals("")`

I dont know how can it be because i check before that if unWanted isnt null.
Thank for helping :)

```
public String[] setExercies(){

DataBaseMain data = new DataBaseMain(this);
data.open();
String[] unWanted = data.getAllUnwantedExercies();  
String[] exits = data.getAllExercies();
data.close();

if(unWanted == null)
    return exits;

int f = 0;

for(int g = 0; g < unWanted.length; g++)
{
    if(unWanted[g].equals(""))
        f++;
}

String[] temp = new String[unWanted.length-f];
f = 0;

for (int k = 0; k < unWanted.length; k++){
    if(unWanted[k].equals("") == false)
    {
        temp[f] = unWanted[k];
        f++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like `unWanted[g]` is `null` at some value of `g`. Do a `null` check before applying the `equals`.

Comment: have you checked if this function (data.getAllUnwantedExercies();) is returning values and not null?

Comment: when compairing a string to a constant, invert the test such that the constant .equals the non constant.  for example, in stead of `blam.equals("hoot")` which will throw an NPE if blam is null, use `"hoot".equals(blam)` which wil lnever throw an NPE.

Comment: @DwB: on the other hand, detecting the NPE early is often a good thing, because having a null element in the array is probably a bug that needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for some reason your `getAllUnwantedExercies()` is returning null.

u can check null in here

```
for(int g = 0; g < unWanted.length; g++)
{
    if(unwanted[g] != null && unWanted[g].equals(""))
        f++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The string value inside unWanted is null. You'll need an additional null check. Use one of these depending on your intent

```
for(int g = 0; g < unWanted.length; g++)
{
    if(unWanted[g] == null || unWanted[g].equals(""))
        f++;
}

for(int g = 0; g < unWanted.length; g++)
{
    if(unWanted[g] != null && unWanted[g].equals(""))
        f++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the values in your array unWanted is null. You'll have to find out which index contains it but you could try:

```
for(int g = 0; g < unWanted.length; g++)
{
  String unWantedVal = unWanted[g];
  if(unWantedVal == null)
     System.out.println("Index " + g + " has a null value!");
  else if(unWantedVal.equals(""))
        f++;
}
```